# Should I reply to a university admission offer email?

Tags: graduate-admissions, etiquette, email

I got an admission offer email from one of the universities that I've applied to for a graduate course. It seems to be from a departmental email ID and has generic content with my name and address filled in. It also contains details about next steps, documents, deadlines, etc.

Am I expected to reply to this email? Since I am waiting for other universities' decisions, how do I send a neutral reply to this one?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you have specific questions or the email explicitly asks for a response, the answer is likely no.

Comment: It is an automatically generated email with no personally written text?

Comment: @Drecate - Makes sense.

Comment: @daniel.neumann - Yep, templated email.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It isn't necessary to reply to an offer of admission until you decide whether you will accept.

If you feel you must reply, you can simply say something like "Thank you for letting me know.  I will be sure to let you know my decision before the deadline."

Comment: To follow up with this approach, I have 3-4 months to make a decision. So that late of a reply won't seem awkward, right?

Comment: @shadow: No.  Nobody is expecting a reply until you have made a decision.